# Pass literal control from one page to another

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have this literal control in Page1:

```
 string s1 = "<table>"
           + "<tr>"
           + "<td>AAA</td>"
           + "<td>AAA</td>"
           + "</tr>"
           + "<tr>"
           + "<td>BBB</td>"
           + "<td>BBB</td>"
           + "</tr>"
           + "</table>"
           + "<br />";

 string s2 = "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.open('Page2.aspx','','Height=500,width=500')\" value=\"pop up\" />";

 LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(s1 + s2);
 Div1.Controls.Add(lc);
```

As you can see, it is a simple HTML table and button.
What I want to do is to click the button, pop up Page2.aspx, and add the literal control (lc) without the button to a Div in Page2.aspx (Div1).

I can't get this to work.
Page1 must not post back to the server to accomplish this.

Comment: @SWeko - No. Sorry if I made it sound like it was.

Comment: You have to realize that this will be *horribly* insecure.

Comment: @SystemDown - That's OK for this project.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm sure there will be a safer and saner way of doing it.

Comment: @SystemDown - I have a report that takes a while to load. I was hoping to have a Print/CSV/Excel button to temporarily open the table in a pop up window without having to post back to the server to fetch data again. Also was hoping to not have to use a session object to store the data.

Comment: How large will this HTML be? Give me the worst case scenario.

Comment: @SystemDown - The size of the HTML is not too bad. Worst case scenario would be about 2,000 KB. But due to the complexity of the data, it takes several seconds for the server to calculate the results and serve the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three ways to pass data between pages:

- GET values
- POST values
- Server variables (sessions ... etc)

Server variables are the most flexible solution and shouldn't result in a severe performance hit if used correctly. But you've ruled that option out.

POST values are another option. They're stored in HiddenFields inside your form, but you need to do a form submit in order to use them. And since you're using a link that opens up a pop up, this isn't a good solution.

This leaves GET values. Which is storing the value inside the query string of the URL. This *would* work, but it has a size limitation of around 8 KB. If you can keep the size of your HTML to within that, then what you would need to do is [Base64 encode](http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/) the HTML (this isn't encrypting it, it's just packaging it into one neat string), use the encoded string as part of the URL (i.e. "`Page2.aspx?data=SomeString`"), then in Page2 get that values using `Request.Params["data"]` then Base64 decode it, and place that value in the local Literal control.

But, it seems your value is much much larger than that. So that leaves you to use a server variable, or store your HTML somewhere and pass a reference to it. For instance, you can save the generated HTML inside a database with a unique identifier key and just pass the key to the Page2 which would query the DB for the actual HTML.

Answer (score -1):

This is a **terrible way of programming**, you should the `.aspx` page handle the HTML and the Code behind part handle the data.

for example, add the data (your `DataTable` for example) to a session object, or make use of the `GridView` control where you simply do:

```
myGridView.DataSource = dt;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

and because you are reusing the same thing, **you can use a User Control** that has the `myGridView` on it.

This way, you're not handling HTML format on your Code Handling page and you are reusing a control where, tomorrow, if anything happens, you can easily change just one file, and all places that has that control will be modified automatically.

---

If you still don't care much about decent programming rules, you can add your Literal control to, for example, a session object and call it on the second page:

```
LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(s1 + s2);

// Add control to a Session instance
Session["myLiteralControl"] = lc;

Div1.Controls.Add(lc);
```

in your other page:

```
LiteralControl lc = (Literal)Session["myLiteralControl"];
Div1.Controls.Add(lc);
```

Comment: It may seem like a terrible way of programming, but you don't know the specifics of this project, you don't know if it is a public, private or intranet site. How can you say that?... also, I realize I could use a session object, but I was trying to avoid going that route.

Comment: @Administrateur - Then it would be best to give more specifics about your project. Specifically what you're trying to achieve, and why are you thinking of doing it this way. Also, you never mentioned that sessions are not to be used in your question.

Comment: no mater what project is what will be, **"If you're doing something, always do the best you can!"** and instead of complain, learn from others... As @SystemDown said, there are no details on such matter, you should look again to your own question, here we are only trying to help each other.